# struggle to run python script with crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron, smtplib

I am currently working on some python scripts that involve sending emails to recipients with information I scrape from the web or by API.

The first script, magic_sea.py scrapes magicseaweed for wave heights in certain locations. The second one uses an API to get weather data.

Both scripts run as they should when I type in the command and a second later
I recieve the inteded email.

`python3 <script.py>`

But only the first one runs when I put them in the crontab like this

`* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /path/to/script.py >> crontab_log.txt
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /path/to/second_script.py >> crontab_log.txt`

I am using the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3.5` in both scripts

looking at the crontab_log.txt file, they both seem to run fine.
But I only recieve emails from the first scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of logging:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /path/to/script.py >> crontab_log.txt
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /path/to/second_script.py >> crontab_log.txt
```

only sends stdout to the log file, not errors.  You can fix that by using `2>&1` to send stderr to stdout like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /path/to/script.py >> crontab_log.txt 2>&1
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.5 /path/to/second_script.py >> crontab_log.txt 2>&1
```

That should allow you to identify and correct any errors.

If you still don't see what you need, add logging all through script 2 to see what is happening while it is being executed by cron.

Comment: Great advice! I made the mistake of assuming that because the image file I am using in the email was in the same folder as the python file I didn't have to specify the path to it, but as i have learned, this is not where cron executes the script. Thank you :)